# How to explode nested array of structure with unknown array length in Hive?

Tags: hive

I have a hive table emp_test as below:

```
'name' as string <br>
'testing' as array< struct < code:string,tests:array < struct < testtype:string,errorline:string>>>>
```

and have column values :"name" as "JOHN" and "testing" as

```
[{"code":"cod1234","tests":[{"testtype":"java","errorline":"100"},{"testtype":"C++","errorline":"10000"}]},<br>
 {"code":"cod6790","tests":[{"testtype":"hive","errorline":"10"},{"testtype":"pig","errorline":"978"},{"testtype":"spark","errorline":"35"}]}
]
```

How to select these values and store in another table

```
emp_test_detail(name,code,testtype,errorline) as

JOHN cod1234 java       100 <br>
JOHN cod1234 C++        10000<br>
JOHN cod6790 hive       10<br>
JOHN cod6790 pig        978<br>
JOHN cod6790 spark      35<br>
```

i have tried below query but got error :

```
*insert into emp_test_detail select <br>
        emp_tasting.code, <br>
        emp_tasting.emp_tests.testtype, <br>
        emp_tasting.emp_tests.errorline from emp_test <br> 
lateral view explode(testing) mytest as emp_tasting <br>
lateral view explode(testing[0].tests) mytest as emp_tasting;* <br>
```

and here I don't know the exact length of testing array.so how to reference array fields?

Please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your example query the error is likely related to using `emp_tasting`, the same column alias for both `lateral view explode` lines. They need to have different aliases.

To un-nest an array two levels deep, you need to explode the first array, then refer to the alias of that exploded array when exploding the nested array.

For example, you wanted `name, code, testtype, errorline`

`name` is available directly in the table
`code` is available from the first explode
`testtype` and `errorline` are available from the nested explode.

*Note I am looking at your schema, not the data you've listed, it's easier for me to reason about*

**This query should do what you want**

```
SELECT
  name,
  testingelement.code,
  test.testtype, 
  test.errorline 
FROM emp_test 
LATERAL VIEW explode(testing) testingarray as testingelement
LATERAL VIEW explode(testingelement.tests) testsarray as test;
```

**Table and column aliases**

*Note that explode has two aliases added after it, the first is for the table expression it generates, the second is for the column(s).*

So in this example

`LATERAL VIEW explode(testing) testingarray as testingelement`

`testingarray` is the table alias
`testingelement` is the *array* column alias you need to reference to extract the fields within the struct.

**Skipping the first explode**

If you only wanted fields directly from the table and from the nested array then you can shortcut that query by doing a single LATERAL VIEW explode to

`LATERAL VIEW explode(testing.tests) testsarray as test`

The problem with that is it will also explode empty arrays, and you can't use * star expansion, you have to refer to field names explicitly. That's not a bad thing.

What is a bad thing is having to use array indexes in a query. As soon as you start writing `field[0]` then something smells funky. That would only ever get the first element of the array, and as you've said it relies on knowing the size of the array beforehand which would have very limited use cases.